# Populate spinner from database with previous values

Tags: android, database, android-spinner

I have an activity with edittexts and spinners. I set the values in each one and then save them in a db. Now in a second activity with the exact same xml file i want to automatically populate them all with the values from the db in order to modify them. I used .setText in order to populate the edittexts and it works fine. What can i use to populate the spinners??

Sample code follows...

```
package com.alex.example;
import ...

public class Profile extends Activity {

    DatabaseHelperUser db = new DatabaseHelperUser(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile);
        final EditText edtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        final Spinner spnSex = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnSex);
        final ImageButton btnConfirm = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnChickListed);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        final int userid = b.getInt("id");
        final User user = db.getUser(userkid);

        edtName.setText(user.get_name());
        spnSex.
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Load your items into an array `array_spinner`
Then:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
spnSex.setAdapter(adapter);
spnSex.setSelection(value); // if you want to select a value that you stored somewhere
```

Comment: None of the spinner values are in the database except the one that I have chosen whet i set the user. How can i put them all in the array?? Sorry if the question seems silly but i am brand new in android.